# Probability of three faces with different colors sharing a corner

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Ram painted the six faces of a cube with 6 different colors- Red, yellow, white, blue, green and black. What is the probability that the faces with the colors-Red ,yellow and white have a corner in common?

My take:
Total number of ways of painting the cube with these $6$ colors is $\frac{720}{8} =90$. How do i proceed from here? Could anyone please help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of distinguishable possible cubes is $30$.

This is because if you fix one colour, you can choose $5$ to go on the opposite face, and the remaining four can be arranged in a circle in $\frac{4!}{4}=6$ ways, allowing for rotations of the same configuration.

As for the numerator of this probability, you can arrange the three chosen colours in a circle in $\frac{3!}{3}=2$ ways, and independently arrange the remaining three colours in $3!=6$ ways, so the total is $12$ desired configurations.

So the answer is $\frac{12}{30}=\frac25$

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution which does not require us to know the number of indistinguishable ways to paint the faces of a cube with $6$ colors.

Number the faces from $1$ to $6$.  There are $6!$ ways to assign the $6$ colors to the faces, all of which we assume are equally likely.

To count the number of arrangements in which red, yellow and white have a common corner, there are $8$ ways to select the corner, then $3!$ ways to arrange the designated colors on the adjacent faces, and then $3!$ ways to assign the remaining colors to faces.  So the probability is
$$\frac{8 \times 3! \times 3!}{6!} = \frac{2}{5}$$